# Transparent Form Control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, transparency

I have the following code I found online: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/VBWinFormExAeroToClient-f0d42b34

And I've been tweaking it to work with my own application.

I need a Small 500x30 px Form.

I've been reading through the demo code that is provided in that link, but I can't seem to find where to modify the "Demo Form" size/shape.

Ideally, I'd simply like a 1 form version of this demo, that on load applies a full region of transparency. (Which I can likely figure out)

The problem I'm having, is where can I draw objects on this Demo Form?

I've got the GlassForm, but objects, and other properties on this, are not passed to the "DemoForm".

I have no idea why.

---

Long story short, I want a single basic transparent form, which I can add other style properties like Size, Form-border, and objects like TextBoxes, Labels, and Buttons.

I cannot seem to accomplish this with the given demo.

---

I was able to change the form size/border, but using the following code when the DemoForm is called.

```
DemoForm.Show()
DemoForm.Width = (500)
DemoForm.Height = (30)
DemoForm.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow
DemoForm.TopMost = True
```

But I still can't figure out how to modify the from from the Form Designer, nor how to add controls to the new generated form.

Comment: You could inherit the Form and add properties as you want. Then you could inherit this form in your designer...

Comment: You'll have to excuse me, but I'm not sure what you mean by inherit the Form.

Comment: Are you just wanting a transparent form that you can drag and drop controls on in the designer with other properties? If so let me know this is what you would like and I will post solution...

Comment: I believe so, I'd like to design my form with the standard Designer tools, by dragging my objects on, positioning them as I like, then writing code for said objects. As well, I'd like the Aero transparency that I've mentioned above. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I posted a great solution for you. Please see the solution and let me know if that works out.

Comment: Awesome thanks!!! I'll read through it shortly and see how it works. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Set the Forms opacity:

```
DemoForm.Show()
DemoForm.Opacity = 0.85
DemoForm.Width = (500)
DemoForm.Height = (30)
DemoForm.TopMost = True
```

The Opacity can be set between 0 and 1.

Comment: This works, but doesn't give me the Aero effect from in the Demo. Though this will be remembered as a fall back.

Comment: What do you mean with 'Aero' effect, could you be more specfic, I think the `FormBorderStyle` is messing up your form, could you try my updated answer, without using FixedToolWindow.

Comment: The aero effect is the same as the Windows 7 window frame. Where it gives it its glossy blue colour. http://i.imgur.com/Ajmd7aa.png

Answer (score 0):

In short you can change the opacity of a form, **but children controls opacity will change as well**. In order to get past that you can set the `Form.BackColor` property and the `Form.TransparencyKey` to a color that your form isn't using. For my test I had chosen `Color.Pink`, but you can change this as needed.

***Note: When you change this behavior: labels, check-boxes and radio-buttons background color can't be transparent, any other color is fine.***

I created a class named: TransitionForm, this inherits the `System.Windows.Forms.Form` control that you are going to need to inherit to make your other forms transparent.

Here's the TransitionForm class...

```
Imports System.ComponentModel


Public Class TransitionForm
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

Private intBorderThickness As BorderThick
Private clrBorderColor As Color
Private IsFormBeingDragged As Boolean = False
Private MouseDownX As Integer = 0
Private MouseDownY As Integer = 0

Public Enum BorderThick
    Light
    Medium
    Thick
End Enum

<System.ComponentModel.Description("Select border thickness")>
Public Property BorderThickness As BorderThick
    Get
        Return intBorderThickness
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As BorderThick)
        intBorderThickness = value
        Me.Refresh()
    End Set
End Property

<System.ComponentModel.Description("Select border color")>
Public Property BorderColor As Color
    Get
        Return clrBorderColor
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Color)
        clrBorderColor = value
        Me.Refresh()
    End Set
End Property

Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    Me.Size = New Size(500, 30)
    Me.BorderColor = Color.LightBlue
    Me.BorderThickness = BorderThick.Light
    Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None

End Sub

Private Sub TransitionForm_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Me.BackColor = Color.Pink 'This can be what ever color you want as long as it's not on your form...
    Me.TransparencyKey = Color.Pink 'This can be what ever color you want as long as it's not on your form...
End Sub

Private Sub TransitionForm_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        IsFormBeingDragged = True
        MouseDownX = e.X
        MouseDownY = e.Y
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TransitionForm_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
    If IsFormBeingDragged Then
        Dim temp As Point = New Point()

        temp.X = Me.Location.X + (e.X - MouseDownX)
        temp.Y = Me.Location.Y + (e.Y - MouseDownY)
        Me.Location = temp
        temp = Nothing
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TransitionForm_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseUp
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        IsFormBeingDragged = False
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub TransitionForm_Paint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    Dim pPen As Pen = Nothing

    Select Case BorderThickness
        Case BorderThick.Light
            pPen = New Pen(BorderColor, 1)
        Case BorderThick.Medium
            pPen = New Pen(BorderColor, 3)
        Case BorderThick.Thick
            pPen = New Pen(BorderColor, 5)
    End Select

    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pPen, 0, 0, Me.Width - 1, Me.Height - 1)
End Sub
End Class
```

Now that you have the class, you need to inherit this class into the form that you want to use it in.

For example: Double click the designer file for the form that you want to make transparent. Then you need to type:

```
  Inherits TransitionForm 'This is the new class
```

[image]

You can expand on the properties of this new class as well. Some of them I have included are: BorderThickness (size of the border) & BorderColor (color of the border). I also implemented drag-and-drop of this new form as well because when you turn off the `FormBorderStyle.None` you can't drag the form anymore.

Here is a quick mock-up of this control, it's not the best but I am sure you can tell it does what you want; also ***it still has the Aero Effects that you wanted for the controls***. Also just drag and drop any control onto the form you want.

[image]

Comment: This is a great example, however, I'm trying to get a glassy background, as shown here: i.imgur.com/Ajmd7aa.png